# saving image into core data not being counted

Tags: swift, core-data, count, delegates, binary-data

In my swift code below the goal is to save the image and print the number for the counting. I am getting a optional being unwrapped error at the print line. Someone told me to resolve this I needed to do a context.perform but that is still causing the same error message.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
    let gwen = UIImage(named: "f.jpeg")
    if let imageData = gwen.self?.pngData() {
        DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.saveImage(data: imageData)
    }

    let arr = DataBaseHelper.shareInstance.fetchImage()
    let jake = Int()
    
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    
    
    context.perform {
        print("core data number is : ", arr[jake].img!.count)
    }}




class DataBaseHelper {
    
    static let shareInstance = DataBaseHelper()
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    func saveImage(data: Data) {
        let imageInstance = Info(context: context)
        imageInstance.img = data
            
        do {
            try context.save()
            print("Image is saved")
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchImage() -> [Info] {
        var fetchingImage = [Info]()
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Info")
        
        do {
            fetchingImage = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [Info]
        } catch {
            print("Error while fetching the image")
        }
        
        return fetchingImage
    }
   
   
    
  
    
   
}
```

Comment: This question looks familiar. Why use a context.perform on the print statement, what use is this?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson someone told me to use I don't think it makes sense either

Comment: Are you sure that the image `gwen` and the `imageData` are not nil?